# A transformation that combines two smooth functions within a bounded subset of domain?

Tags: special-functions

Suppose we have two smooth functions $f(x), g(x)$, and we would like to obtain another smooth function $h(x)$ that is as close to $g(x)$ as possible within a bounded subset of the domain and as close to $f(x)$ as possible in the rest part of domain, formally,

- $|h(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x\in(a, b)$
- $|h(x) - f(x)| < \delta$ for $x\in(-\infty , a]\cup[b , +\infty)$

where $\epsilon > 0, \delta > 0$

We are looking for an analytic form of a transformation for this purpose, i.e. $h(x) = \mathcal{T}_{(a, b)}(f(x), g(x))$.

Are there any existing or closely related literature in the community  ?

Note: To describe the problem in the simplest form, we only use one dimensional case, but it demonstrates the same problem in more general cases  (e.g. scalar-valued function with multiple variables)

Comment: So it is necessary that $f$ and $g$ satisfy $|f(a)-g(a)|<\epsilon+\delta$ and $|f(b)-g(b)|<\epsilon+\delta$. And if on the other hand they do, then $h$ can be easily found mollifying $\chi_{(a,b)}g+  \big(1-\chi_{(a,b)} \big)f$